# SQL: Multiple Where Clause based on multiple filters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql

How do I write an SQL query that has nested filters.

Info: 2 search filters

1st filter: Id, Name, Date
2nd filter: depending on first, for Id: exact, range; for Name: exact, like; for Date: exact, range.

In LINQ code its was done something like:

```
theList = somelistFromDb;
case filter1
   case "Id"
       if filter2 == "exact"
          theList.where(x => x == searchkey);
       else if filter 2 == "range"
          theList.where(x => x >= searchkey && x<=searchkey2);
   case "Name"
       if filter2 == "exact"
          theList.where(x => x == searchkey);
       else if filter2 == "like"
          theList.where(x => x.contains("searchkey));
...
```

How do I convert the above LINQ Pseudocode to SQL?

Comment: @MarcGravell - if they were the same values involved in both comparisons, I'd agree with you, but there seem to be 3 values involved here (`x`, `searchKey` and `searchKey2`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I missed that, ta

Comment: The "theList" variable from the above code was returned from a stored procedure. The SP will "return all" and the filtering and sorting was done in C#. The task will be to incorporate the above pseudocode to the SP so everything is done on DB server for "optimization" and the list returned will be already filtered and sorted. Btw, thanks guys...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
...
WHERE
  (:filterParam='Id' AND <all the Id filter conditions> here)
OR
  (:filterParam='Name' AND <all the Name filter conditions> here)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from [Table] where 
((@filter1='Id') and 
  ((filter2='exact' and [Table].[Id]=@searchkey) OR
   (filter2='range' and [Table].[Id]>=@searchkey and [Table].[Id]<=@searchkey2) ))
OR
((@filter1='Name') and 
.....
```

Comment: I tried to implement it but I got data conversion error. Do you have any work around in converting the data?

Comment: I don't know you what data do you use so I cann't give you an advise

Comment: The searchKey in my case could be a string, an int, or a date. If the filter2 is range, in the 'Id' search, i have to convert those to int. But if the filter1 is 'Name' and I will pass in 'Harry' it will throw error because it could not be converted to int. It seems everything was evaluated not short circuited.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a single TSQL query that satisfies or excludes all the conditions in one go is usually very suboptimal - it leads to terrible query plans. Trying to do all the thinking in TSQL is... somewhat ugly - TSQL simply isn't a great language for it.

So: the way I would usually do this is by building the query in C#, for example:

```
static void AppendFilter(StringBuilder filter, string clause)
{
    filter.Append(filter.Length == 0 ? " where " : " and ").Append(clause);
}

StringBuilder filter = new StringBuilder();
if(/* some condition */)
    AppendFilter(filter, "row.Foo = @foo");
if(/* some condition */)
    AppendFilter(filter, "row.Bar > @bar"); 
// ...
string tsql = "select * from SomeTable row" + filter.ToString();
// pack params, exec
```

This:

- extends to any number of filters
- generates appropriate TSQL per filter combination, for optimal query-plans
- is simple to maintain

Personally, I'd also use dapper to do the execution, as that has (basic) parameter analysis built in, allowing simple:

```
var rows = conn.Query<SomeType>(tsql, new { foo, bar, ... }).ToList();
```

(yet it will still send only the necessary parameters)

An alternative, though, is to add the parameters in each `if`.